# Sphere rotating in several directions simultaneously?

Tags: rotations, spheres

By rotation I'm here only referring to an object rotating in relation to itself, not in relation to any other object. Also I should add that the axis of rotation should be through the center of the object.

For example with a cylindrical object it's easy to see how it can rotate both around the cylindrical axis and around a diameter axis simultaneously, like this:

http://s29.postimg.org/5bdnfjbg3/cyl.gif

But with a sphere I find it harder to visualize several simultaneous rotations.

How many directions can a sphere rotate in simultaneously? How can we visualize different numbers of simultaneous rotations?

Is there a .gif, video, applet or similar that shows several simultaneous rotations of a sphere so that it's easier to visualize it?

Comment: A composition of rotations around a single point is still a rotation. So looked at the right way, a sphere rotating "in multiple directions" is actually just a sphere rotating in a single, different direction.

Comment: @mixedmath Interestingly, in 4+ dimensions this is no longer the case; you can have [double rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space#Double_rotations) in multiple mutually orthogonal planes at once.

Comment: The cylinder isn't actually spinning in two directions either.  There's a fixed point.  It's not possible for a sphere (or a cylinder, or a cube or a .. ) to spin the way you describe.

Comment: Even numbered dimensions this is true.  Odd numbered dimensions it is not.

Comment: @fleablood To clarify: It is true in $\ge4$ dimensions that there are rotations that are not simple (described by only one plane of rotation), while in odd dimensions it is also true that every rotation has a nonzero fixed point (so in say dimension 5 we can rotate in "two directions at once", but we can't rotate the entire object smoothly with no fixed points like we can in 4D).

Comment: 3 dimensions is odd numbered, so are you saying it's possible here, fleablood? Also, I'm right now holding a pen (cylindrical object) and I'm rotating it both in the cylindrical axis and the diameter axis at the same time... it seems quite possible!

Comment: @Signal You are actually rotating your pen in an axis which goes diagonal to the pen. Because of the shape of the pen, it is easiest to understand its motion as a composition of two rotations, but that doesn't change that it is sufficient to describe it as one "diagonal rotation". Also note that if you keep moving your pen you can get more complex or nonlinear motion, this only applies to "instantaneous motion" or else regular motion in a consistent direction.

Comment: A rotation around a diagonal axis of the pen is different from how I mean. I made a gif explaining how I mean the cylinder rotates: http://s29.postimg.org/5bdnfjbg3/cyl.gif as you can see it rotates in two directions simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

This is [Euler's rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_rotation_theorem). The comment by @mixedmath is already a suitable answer, but it can also be understood as a consequence of one of the more peculiarly-named theorems, the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). Suppose that your sphere was in fact rotating in multiple directions at once. You can describe what direction each point on the body is moving, and this forms a vector field over the sphere (Imagine combing a coconut in the direction of rotation). At this point the hairy ball theorem says that there is some singular point where there is no defined direction of motion - because it is on the axis of rotation. Since it is a rigid body, everything else must rotate around this axis in circles, and we have simple rotational motion.

(This theorem is actually a bit overkill, since it applies even to nonlinear vector fields, but it makes a good mental image.)

Since OP requested a GIF visualization, consider the following image of a double rotation in 4D, and note that every point on the object is in motion (although the sides of the tessaract are hidden because they would make it hard to see what is going on):

[image: Tessaract rotation]

It is this situation (a rotation with no fixed points) that Euler's theorem says is impossible in 3D.

Comment: So these theorems are saying it is impossible in 3D. Then what about the twofold rotation I illustrated in this image? http://s29.postimg.org/5bdnfjbg3/cyl.gif This is not rotation around a diagonal axis as you wrote in an earlier comment but there are two rotations going on simultaneously. Do these theorems say that the movement I show in the picture is impossible?

Comment: @Signal That has to do with what I wrote earlier about more complex motion. The axis of rotation moves along a conical path; free body rotation for cylindrical objects says that this is always the case (angular momentum is constant, while the angular velocity, or axis of rotation precesses around it in a cone). For non-cylindrical objects, the overall motion can be even more complex, even chaotic. But at each *instant* we can measure the instantaneous motion, and in this case the motion is simplified to the case discussed in these theorems, ... (con't)

Comment: ... where it just takes the form of an axis of rotation surrounded by points moving around it. The linear analog of this is that I can move my finger around in figure eights or write my name or whatever, but if we zoom in to just one infinitesimal piece of this motion, it will just be me moving my finger in a straight line in some well-defined direction.

Answer (score 1):

A sphere cannot rotate around several axis "simultaneously". Whatever the motion, you can describe it as a rotation around a single axis. (See the Rodrigues'rotation formula.)